# Allow questions to be filtered based on user preference

Tags: feature-request, tag-watching, preferences

I would like to be able to prefer certain tags and only see those questions when I log into any of the Stack Overflow trilogy of sites.

Say I'm interested in C#, ASP.NET MVC, and Silverlight and I select those as my filtered interesting tags. When I log into Stack Overflow I will only see questions that are tagged with those labels.

Answer (score 1):

This is partially implemented already.

Go to your profile, and check the `prefs` tab. Take note of the "Hide Ignored Bags" button (and the "Add" button for the ignored tags list, of course).

Answer (score 1):

You can also implement this by bookmarking searches. Unfortunately, you would need to do each tag separately, as by default the tag URLs implement an "AND" mechanism.

To bookmark, use the following URL:

- http://www.stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/`tag-name`